# Elasticsearch: Does edgeNGram token filter work on non english tokens?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, cjk

I am trying to setup a new mapping for an index. Which is going to support partial keyword search and auto-complete requests powered by ES.

edgeNGram token filter with whitespace tokeniser seems a way to go. Till now my setting looks something like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test_ngram_2?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "customNgram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "customNgram"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "customNgram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": "3",
                    "max_gram": "18",
                    "side": "front"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
```

The problem is with Japanese words! Does NGrams work on japanese letters?
For e.g.:
【11月13日13時まで、フォロー&RTで応募！】

There is no whitespace in this - The document is not searchable with partial keywords, is that expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the icu_tokenizer which adds support for foreign languages https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu-tokenizer.html

> Tokenizes text into words on word boundaries, as defined in UAX #29:
>   Unicode Text Segmentation. It behaves much like the standard
>   tokenizer, but adds better support for some Asian languages by using a
>   dictionary-based approach to identify words in Thai, Lao, Chinese,
>   Japanese, and Korean, and using custom rules to break Myanmar and
>   Khmer text into syllables.

PUT icu_sample

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_icu_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that to use it in your index you need to install the appropriate plugin:

`bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu`

Adding this to your code:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test_ngram_2?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "customNgram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "customNgram"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "customNgram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": "3",
                    "max_gram": "18",
                    "side": "front"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
```

Normally you would search an autocomplete like this using the `standard` analyzer, instead add an analyzer to your mapping also with the `icu_tokenizer` (but not the `edgeNGram` filter) and apply this to your query at search time, or explicitly set it as the `search_analyzer` for the field you apply `customNgram` to.

Comment: thank, I would look into this. But I guess will still need to make ngram work for auto-complete use case.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you would apply this to your code